# Show that there is a sequence $(P_n)$ of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $||P_n||\to0$ & $\lim_{n\to\infty} S(g,P_n)$ for the $g(x)$ defined.

Tags: analysis, integer-partitions

Let $g(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
1/x, & \text{if }x\not\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$, $x\in[0,1]$. Show that $\exists$ sequence $(P_n)$ of tagged partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $||P_n||\to0$ & $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} S(g,P_n)$ exists.

Why is $g\not\in\mathscr{R}[0,1]$?

I don't really know where to start.

Comment: $S$ is a Riemann sum?

Comment: Yes, $S$ is a Riemann sum.

Comment: Note that every open interval contains a rational number and an irrational number.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Choose as tags rational numbers, and any sufficiently small partition.

$(2)$ Is $g$ bounded on $[0,1]$?

Comment: If we use $g(x)=\begin{cases}  0, & x\in\Bbb Q\\ 1, & x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$, then the same can be arranged with $S(g,P_n)$. But this $g$ is bounded.

Comment: Shouldn't I take the tags of the irrationals? Then I would have that there exists $x\not\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $x<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ so for that $x, g(x)$ is unbounded so $g$ is not integrable on any interval with that $x$. Or is it that the tags are not what is used in the sums/ integrals?

Comment: @TedShifrin Who were you addresing?

Comment: @Pedro: You :P My point is there is something more crucial going on here. The convergence of a *particular* sequence of Riemann sums tells us nothing. This is one reason I prefer upper and lower sums.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that. I am just telling the OP how to find a sequence of tagged partitions $\Pi_n$ such that $|\Pi_n|\to 0$ and $S(g,\Pi_n)\to 0$; and the second point is to explain the failure of Riemann integrability.

Comment: @Pedro: Not to beat a dead horse, but that was my original point. Unboundness is really a red (or purple, if you prefer) herring here.

Comment: @TedShifrin How so?

Comment: Am I missing something? See my very first comment!

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't really understand what you want to get at to with the first comment, that's why I asked in the first place.

Comment: @Pedro: By choosing shrinking (say, uniform) partitions and all rational (or all irrational) tags with my function $g$ — which *is* bounded — I get constant Riemann sums. Yet $g$ fails to be Riemann integrable.

Comment: @TedShifrin True, but the sums are not equal if you choose irrational and rational values. At any rate, by choosing appropriate partitions with irrational points we can find a sum that diverges to $+\infty$. You can also say $\overline{\int_0^1}f=+\infty$ and $\underline{\int_0^1} f=0$.